# ASP.NET 4 Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-routing

I am working on an ASP.NET 4.0 web forms project that uses page routing to serve up CMS content.

The exact code used is:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ContentNavigateUrl", "{*navigateurl}", "~/Router.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { }, new RouteValueDictionary { { "navigateurl", @"[-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+(\.aspx(\?.+)?)?" } });
```

The website has a mixture of fixed aspx pages and CMS pages served up by Router.aspx.

The CMS content has URLs like /xyz/abc.

Everything works well except when an actual folder exists and as there is no default page in the folder IIS sends a 403 error (directory browsing is not enabled).

As an example:

There is an actual folder called /xyz which has some aspx pages in it but no default page. If I request http://domain.com/xyz I get a 403 error instead of it using Router.aspx as I want it to and displaying my CMS content.

Is there an IIS setting that needs to be changed, or something in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to trap these 403 errors in web.config but it did not appear to do anything: <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Router.aspx"/>

Comment: BTW, what version of IIS are use using? My guess your problem has something to do with handler mappings, try to play with them a bit (for example, try disabling StaticFile handler mapping).

Comment: I have no access to the server other than to copy files there. I believe it is IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding an error mapping for status code 403 to redirect to /Router.aspx in IIS.